# How to resolve sending email subscription error in SSRS

Tags: mysql, t-sql, reporting-services, crystal-reports, scheduled-tasks

How to resolve an email subscription error in SSRS."Failure sending mail: Only absolute directories are allowed for pickup directory. Mail will not be resent"

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you attaching files to it somehow.. is this just a standard email subscription?

Comment: Check the other image on how i set up the subscription @Harry

Comment: Are all subscriptions facing this issue or just one? I would think you probably goofed up on one of your configuration files if you're experiencing this for all subscriptions.